# Remove duplicates from main table but also the relation table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `questions` and `choices`, `choices` has an relation to `questions` with a column called `question_id`. And it also have a foreign constrain on questions table and cascade on delete.

But I manage to get duplicates in the DB. And it would be fairly simple to delete, but I also have to check the `choices` table.. And check to see so they also are duplicates...

In `questions` table, matching content in column `description` and `image` would be a duplicated, and in table `choices`, the `choice`column for that specific question, if that make any sense.

So what it really boils down to is the `choices` table, I think. (sorry really don't understand how I got this problem the start ).

Because, a `questions` "description" column, **can be the same**. But relate to a image, and the answers depending on what the image is showing. And sometimes there is an duplicate image with description, image everything, but the choices are in a different "order".

Hard to explain. But the interesting fields are `description`, `source` and `image`. And `choice` in `choices` table, but they can then be in a different order.

I have have done a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532e2d) with the data I believe is relevant.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `choices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `choice` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `choices_question_id_foreign` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `choices_question_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `questions` (`order`, `description`, `source`, `image`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', null, 'eerrff.png'), #ID 1 (NOT DUPLICATE, NO SOURCE?)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 2 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 3 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 4 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 5 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 6 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 7 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 8 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Is the earth is flat?', 'In a very special community, it is', 'eerrff.png'), #ID 9 (DUPLICATES)
  ('1', 'Look at the image, what is correct?', 'source', 'oopp.png'), #ID 10 (DUPLICATE WITH #12)
  ('1', 'Look at the image, what is correct?', 'source', 'qqww.png'), #ID 11 (NOT DUPLICATE, LOOK CHOICES)
  ('1', 'Look at the image, what is correct?', 'source', 'oopp.png'), #ID 12 (DUPLICATE WITH #10)
  ('1', 'Look at the image, what is correct?', 'source', 'oopp.png'); #ID 13 (NOT DUPLICATE, LOOK CHOICES)

INSERT INTO `choices` (`question_id`, `choice`, `correct`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Yes', 1),
  ('1', 'No', 0),
  ('2', 'Yes', 1),
  ('2', 'No', 0),
  ('3', 'No', 0),
  ('3', 'Yes', 1),
  ('4', 'Yes', 1),
  ('4', 'No', 0),
  ('5', 'No', 0),
  ('5', 'Yes', 1),
  ('6', 'Yes', 1),
  ('6', 'No', 0),
  ('7', 'Yes', 1),
  ('7', 'No', 0),
  ('8', 'No', 0),
  ('8', 'Yes', 1),
  ('9', 'Yes', 1),
  ('9', 'No', 0),
  ('10', 'First is corrct', 1),
  ('10', 'second', 0),
  ('10', 'third', 0),
  ('10', 'fourth', 0),
  ('11', 'b', 0),
  ('11', 'c', 0),
  ('11', 'Number A', 1),
  ('11', 'd', 0),
  ('12', 'third', 0),
  ('12', 'second', 0),
  ('12', 'First is corrct', 1),
  ('12', 'fourth', 0),
  ('13', 'That guy on the left is doin it wrong', 0),
  ('13', 'That guy on the right is doin it wrong', 0),
  ('13', 'That guy in yellow is doin in right', 1),
  ('13', 'That guy green is doin it right', 0);
```

Expected result: Remove duplicates from `questions` table depending on different rows result from `choices`.

Comment: Define what "duplicate" means to you here.

Comment: You did a great job creating the fiddle but you dont show what is considered the duplicated. Show us what result you expect. Also define which row delete and which keep

Comment: I have updates the question, tried to explain better. And updates the fiddle with another example.

Comment: You still havent explain what is a duplicated or show an example

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added comments to sql, hope that sort things out

Comment: Is there any of the case or duplicate data, in the sample Fiddle, that needs to be deleted? Let me know the exact record.

Comment: Yes in the example it would be #2-9, #12,

Answer (score 0):

Below will give you list of all question_id that have same choices of different questions:

```
select distinct c1.* from choices c1 join choices c2 
on c1.question_id != c2.question_id 
and c1.choice = c2.choice 
order by choice
```

Comment: Thanks! That gives me about 2,178,620 rows, took 50 seconds. Im not really sure what to make of it =)

Comment: Nice work! So now I would like to delete all questions, based on that return. but not the "first" row. So the duplicates is deleted. Is this possible in mysql?